# Android java.lang.IllegalArgumentException "Invalid primitive conversion from long to int" Exception just in release build

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm developing an android application using `kotlin` and everything was fine till now that I'm getting the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid primitive conversion from long to int` exception on some android devices.

The exception is occurring just in the release build of the application and unfortunately, I have no clue how to debug or properly analyze the stack trace to get to know the exact problem.

The stack trace is as below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid primitive conversion from long to int
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getInt(Field.java)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:946)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1463)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1416)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:686)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1376)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:711)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3496)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:746)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Can you attach the java files, It looks like a java error, Possibly in java code somewhere, it is trying to int cast a long in the wrong way.

Comment: @SujalKumar I don't know which part of the code is causing the problem to share it.

Comment: @SiddharthBhattacharjee Actually I have no java code. The project is kotlin.

Comment: Does your release build have proguard enabled?

Comment: @SujalKumar Yes, it has. And the debug build does not have proguard enabled. Is it a problem with proguard?

Comment: @moghaf It would be helpful if you attach your kotlin classes then, It is very difficult to help without seeing any code.

Comment: I am not completely sure but there might be a 3rd party library in your project which needs to be excluded from the proguard optimization to work properly. A similar thing happened to me few days ago and I added some rules in the proguard file and it worked.

Comment: For now, try to disable proguard and test release build in your device.

Comment: @SujalKumar Ok, I will try to exclude the libraries one by one to find out if there is any problem with them. But if it is a problem with the casting thing, shouldn't it encounter the exception in any android device?

Comment: You got a point but I really can't predict without knowing the flow of the code.

Comment: All the information provided by you until now hints that the culprit is a 3rd party library.

Comment: @SujalKumar After commenting out the proguard line in the build.gradle for release build apparently the problem is solved. I think you are right about the 3rd party libraries. I'm going to exclude them one by one. Thanks.

Comment: @SujalKumar Your solution to disable proguard led me to remove proguard lines one by one(after library exclusion didn't solve the problem) to test if it gets to work and yes it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Nice to hear about that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who may have this problem, in my case, it has been solved by removing `-overloadaggressively` from the `proguard-rules.pro` file.